# jQuery or JavaScript with Image sort changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="image">
    <img id="img-1" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif"/> 
    <img id="img-2" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif"/>
    <img id="img-21" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif"/> 
    <img id="img-22" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif"/> 
    <img id="img-31" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif"/> 
    <img id="img-32" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif"/> 
    <img id="img-41" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif"/> 
    <img id="img-42" src="http://www.cma.rw/sites/default/files/default_images/default_image1.gif"/> 
    </div>

    <script>
    $("image").find("img").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            getClass = $this.attr('img')
            splitClass = getClass.split("-")

            if(splitClass[1] <= 20) {
                $this.attr("src", "http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg");

            } else if(splitClass[1] <= 40) {
                $this.attr("src", "http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg");

            } else {
                $this.attr("src", "http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg");
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I want change my images differently. I want the `<img id="img-1" until img-id="img-20">` to be "http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg" and the `<img id="img-21" until img id="img-40">` to be different from the last one, which is not my actual case.
I want to compare images using mathematical operators as "<" ">" "<=" and "=>"

Comment: Value which is less than `20` is always going to be less than `40`

Comment: It's `#image` not `image`

Comment: ok sorry @Vincent G . can you help me ? rayon dabre

Comment: @LinuxDisciple, I had couple of minutes to edit! Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working code. It's `#image` selector, not `image`. And You have to use `prop('id')` or `attr('id')` to get the id value.

And it's `>= 40` not `<= 40` otherwise you'll never get in the condition you wants.

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/4w27k3o4/5/)

```
$("#image").find("img").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        getClass = $this.attr('img')
        splitClass = $this.prop('id').split("-")
        if(splitClass[1] <= 20) {
            $this.attr("src", "http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1");

        } else if(splitClass[1] >= 40) {
            $this.attr("src", "http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/4-small-flowers.jpg");

        } else {
            $this.attr("src", "http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/627/200/3");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't your example give the same result with `<=40` or `>=40`? The `then` and `else` clauses both set the same image... The entire `if` is redundant. His example is worse because ALL cases were the same image...

Comment: I've edited my answer. In the previous example, it **seems** to have the same behaviour (<=40 or >=40) but it was because there was the same image in the two last statement. I updated with 3 differents pictures to see better the difference.
I agree with you, it isn't good if all the images are the same, it is useless in that case.

Comment: @VincentG THANK YOU SO MUCHHHH.. can i ask a question about another issues?   my english is not good and i see your understand.

Answer (score 0):

You're taking `img` attribute. Instead get `'id'` attribute as follow.

```
getClass = $this.attr('id')
```